# TS error on map: does not exist on type in React Hooks Return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Not sure how to fix this TS syntax error:

**Interfaces.tsx**:

```
export interface Company {
  name: string;
}
```

**FeaturedCompanies.tsx**:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Company } from '../Interfaces/Interfaces';

const FeaturedCompanies = () => {
    const [companies, setData] = useState({ companies: [] });
    const featuredCompanies: Array<Company> = [
        { name: 'Sony' },
        { name: 'Nike' },
        { name: 'Lowes' },
        { name: 'Home Depot' },
        { name: 'Adidas' },
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        setData({ companies: featuredCompanies });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {companies.map((company) => <div data-testid="company">{company.name}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FeaturedCompanies;
```

**Error**: Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ companies: any[]; }'

Comment: Your companies is an object with the key `companies`, so you should do `companies.companies.map ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You store in the state an object with companies, I believe the easiest fix would be replace

```
const [companies, setData] = useState({ companies: [] });
```

with

```
const [companies, setData] = useState([]);
```

and change useEffect to:

```
setData(featuredCompanies);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Company } from '../Interfaces/Interfaces';

const FeaturedCompanies = () => {
    const [companies, setData] = useState<Company>([]);
    const featuredCompanies: Company[] = [
        { name: 'Sony' },
        { name: 'Nike' },
        { name: 'Lowes' },
        { name: 'Home Depot' },
        { name: 'Adidas' },
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        setData(featuredCompanies);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {companies.map((company) => <div data-testid="company">{company.name}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FeaturedCompanies;
```